# how can we make DB tables names dynamic in wso2esb?

Tags: sql, wso2, cdata, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

i am trying to store the data in a Database.Here i am able to push data for single table. need is like i want to make use of same sequence for multiple table to push data.
DB:SQL Server
and also need to know how we can pass dynamic variables in cdata. for eg:
 set  where =? ]]>

here how we set as dynamic
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you narrow down your question or provide an example of what behaviour you want? It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: for example DB query to update table we use this format,              
Query:update <table_name> set <column_name> where <condition>.So here i want to make <table_name> as a dynamic value. this we perform in wso2esb

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it works with table names (only used it for values) but at least you could give it a try. Maybe it's working if you set a property with the sql statement and pass that.

```
<statement>
                        <sql>
                             update dbo.table = ? WHERE id = ?</sql>
                        <parameter expression="get-property('transport','TRANSPORT_VAL1')"
                                   type="VARCHAR"/>
                        <parameter expression="get-property('transport','TRANSPORT_VAL2')" type="INTEGER"/>
                     </statement>
```

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for the comment. may i know why we use transport inside get-property. I am a beginner thats why.

Comment: Hi Ashwin. You can access properties from the transport scope like e.g. JMS message properties if you use ´transport´ within get-property. If you want to access local properties you just do get-property('TRANSPORT_VAL1'). You can find a detailed explanation here https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/XPath+Extension+Functions#XPathExtensionFunctions-Synapsescope

Answer (score 0):

Your code almost works. But `dbo.table=<table_name>` didn't fetch the value directly. So tried another way too. Following is the way:

```
DECLARE 
     @tablename AS nvarchar(100),
     @col1 AS nvarchar(100),
     @val1 AS nvarchar(100),
     @val2 AS nvarchar(100);
SET @tablename = '<table_name>';
SET @col1 = '<column_name>';
SET @val1 = '<column1_value>';
SET @val2 = '<column2_value>';
DECLARE @query_a AS nvarchar(500);
SET @query_a = 'Update '+@tablename+' set '+@col1+'='''+@val1+''' WHERE number ='''+@val2+''''
EXECUTE sp_executesql @query_a;
```

inside parameter called `get-property('table_name')`, `get-property('column_name')`.